# How to convert normal date to date with current time

Tags: java, date, datetime

I am facing the following problem, I have a date `dd-mm-yyyy` and I need to convert it to `yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm` (i.e. with the given date and current hours and minutes).

Example : 
Given date : `11-06-2014` , I should get `2014-06-11 09:30`

```
 public String previousDateString(String dateString)
        throws ParseException {
    // Create a date formatter using your format string
    DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm");

    // Parse the given date string into a Date object.
    // Note: This can throw a ParseException.
    Date myDate = dateFormat.parse(dateString);

    // Use the Calendar class to subtract one day
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    calendar.setTime(myDate);
    calendar.setTime(myDate);
    calendar.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR, -1);

    // Use the date formatter to produce a formatted date string
    Date previousDate = calendar.getTime();
    String result = dateFormat.format(previousDate);

    return result;
}
```

I have tried this code but I am getting `2014-06-10 00:00`

Comment: You get 00:00 because you're not setting current time anywhere in your code. Also I don't know why you're substracting one day ¿?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use two Calendar instances, because the Calendar setTime method sets the hours and minutes to zero.

```
package com.ggl.testing;

import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Date;

public class FormatDate {

    private static final DateFormat inputDateFormat =
            new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");
    private static final DateFormat outputDateFormat = 
            new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm");

    private Calendar calendar;

    public String previousDateString(String dateString) 
            throws ParseException {
        Calendar now = Calendar.getInstance();

        calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        Date myDate = inputDateFormat.parse(dateString);
        calendar.setTime(myDate);
        calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 
                now.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY));
        calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 
                now.get(Calendar.MINUTE));

        return outputDateFormat.format(calendar.getTime());
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String dateString = "10-06-2014";
        try {
            String output = 
                    new FormatDate().previousDateString(dateString);
            System.out.println(output);
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

Output - 2014-06-10 10:47

Answer (score 0):

You get `00:00` because the information you pass in `11-06-2014` does not contain hours or minutes.

If you want the hours:minutes in your converted time, then you need to either add more information to your input or get the current hour/minute.

Answer (score 0):

If you have the option of using Java 8 you can write the solution like this:

```
private LocalTime startOfDay = LocalTime.of(9, 30);

public String previousDateString(String dateString) {
    LocalDate yesterday = LocalDate.parse(dateString, DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd-MM-yyyy"));
    LocalDateTime yesterdayTime = LocalDateTime.of(yesterday, startOfDay);
    return yesterdayTime.format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm"));
}
```